# Wants to display date not inserted in Database

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I am retrieving data from Mysql database, the query is like this:

```
SELECT
DATE(cap_newspaper_page.insertDate) AS _Date,
count(*) AS Image_Captured
FROM
cap_newspaper_page
WHERE 
cap_newspaper_page.insertDate BETWEEN '2012-11-01' AND '2012-11-13'
GROUP BY
DATE(cap_newspaper_page.insertDate)
ORDER BY
DATE(cap_newspaper_page.insertDate)
```

and data is shown as
[image]

but i also want to show Null values which is not inserted in database. Like 2012-11-03, 2012-11-04, 2012-11-09, 2012-11-11 are not inserted in database but i want to show them as Null or 0. Like

1. 2012-11-01     581
2. 2012-11-02     587
3. 2012-11-03     0/null
4. 2012-11-04     0/null
5. 2012-11-05         752
6. 2012-11-06         690
7. 2012-11-07     495
8. 2012-11-08     623
9. 2012-11-09         0/null
10. 2012-11-10         921
11. 2012-11-11         0/null
12. 2012-11-12         755

any ideas??

Comment: I want to see a report specific to date range. Those dates which are not in database also want to show as null vlaues.

Comment: I want to see a report specific to daterange.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: What fieds do you have in database (table) `id` and `date`? Can you share your table structure? and What query you are using to get data currently? Share and get answered soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that your dates are in some sort of data structure after had been read from the database. Lets suppose that it can be an array, you can use something like this (just an example):

```
DateTime[] dts = new DateTime[4];
dts[0] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15);
dts[1] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4);
dts[2] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
dts[3] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4);

DateTime dtMax = dts.Max();
DateTime dtMin = dts.Min();
string str = string.Empty;
for (DateTime i = dtMin; i <= dtMax; i = i.AddDays(1))
{
     str += i.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
     str += Environment.NewLine;
}
```